# Simultanous differential equations in Python

Tags: python, differential-equations

[image]

I wanna solve a simultaneous differential equation and based on Lorenz equations:

```
def f(xyz, t, rho, sigma, beta):
    x, y, z = xyz
    return [sigma * (y - x),
            x * (rho - z) - y,
            x * y - beta * z]
```

I Wrote this:

```
def f(xyz, t, rho, sigma, beta):
    x, y, z = xyz
    return [sigma * y(t).diff(t) + sigma * x + beta * y -77,
            x + rho * y - 61]
```

So basically I have another differential of y in the first equation and I tried to take derivative but  it says:

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable"

Can you tell me How can I solve such problems and for second orders of those?

Comment: In the absence of complete code, I can only guess that the issue is with y(t) presumably because y is a float64

Comment: I have some problems with Python syntax so Do you know how to solve the equation above I posted as a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a linear system for the derivatives, call them `xp, yp`. Fortunately it is triangular, so you can solve it via back-substitution. So first solve for `yp` then insert that for `xp`.

```
def f(xy,t):
    x,y = xy
    yp = 61 - (4*x + y)
    xp = 77 - (2*yp + 2*x + 5*x)
    return xp,yp
```

In general you could employ a linear-system solver `numpy.linalg.solve` or a more general solver like `scipy.optimize.fsolve` to extract the derivatives from a system of implicit equations (as far as possible, DAE - systems of differential-algebraic equations can also have this form).

Comment: Thanks this is useful and Can I ask if you have any recommendations like a textbook or a website for the differential equations in Python?

Answer (score 1):

So do u want to solve Lorenz differential equations in Python?

The link below can help you very much with the answer you are trying to find
https://www.programmersought.com/article/82154360499/

or you can solve it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
 
def lorenz(state, t, sigma, beta, rho):
    x, y, z = state
     
    dx = sigma * (y - x)
    dy = x * (rho - z) - y
    dz = x * y - beta * z
     
    return [dx, dy, dz]
```

Comment: No actually, I saw Lorenz and I thought I can solve my problem but It didn't work . I added my problem as a picture Do you know how can I solve it?

Comment: So you are trying to solve the equation from the picture using Python?

Comment: I actually try to find a lecture or tutorial showing how to solve the system of differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you write `y(t)`, Python thinks you are calling a function called `y` with argument `t`, but `y` appears to be a decimal number, not a function.

Python has a dynamic type system, so when you write

```
x, y, z = xyz
```

Python will assign the variable `y` to the data type of the middle value of `xyz`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still couldn't understand what to do to solve the problem.

Comment: Show some code that demonstrates how you're calling f() - i.e. examples (with types and values) of all 5 parameters